# Wcf service slow response for first time, What is the issue?

Tags: wcf, response, delay

We have created the WCF Service and put it on production server.

When i call the service for the first time it's response time comes 8000+ ms and when again i call the same service it's response time is 2000+ ms. What could be the issue for the response time variation?

Can i have any WCF Config settings to resolve this issue?

We have hosted the Service on IIS 7 + Win Server 2012 + SQL Server 2012.

And have the HTTP Bindings as below.

```
<binding name="MyBasicHttpBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2000000" maxArrayLength="2000000" maxNameTableCharCount="2000000"/>
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
```

Comment: Hi Ravi.. This will not help you in getting answers as the question does not contain more information. Provide more information like where you hosted the service?  which binding you are using?
Such specific info can help in isolating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When your service is called at the first time, it is actually created and initialized. So this comes with some preformance penalty.

You can speed-up your first call by using [IIS Auto-Start feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677285(v=azure.10).aspx)